# Photo Spheres & Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, aframe, photosphere

Is it possible to render photo spheres stored in Google Cloud Services? I have uploaded a photo sphere that works without issue when hosting from a local server, but not when stored in a bucket on the Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I am using the image as a sky element in an a-frame scene, but it doesn't render when the source is the GCP url and built in a Google Apps-Script Web App for testing. I also tested the sky element using a photo sphere from Flikr as the source and it had no problems. Does the metadata not get read properly when serving from GCP? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<a-assets>

    <!-- Images. -->
    <img id="skyTexture" src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4734/24508950177_b7b09a1f30_k.jpg">

</a-assets>

<a-sky src="#skyTexture"></a-sky>
```

```
<a-assets>

    <!-- Images. -->
    <img id="skyTexture" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/pano-images/cwm-vcfacility/PANO_20171019_130509_0.jpg">

</a-assets>

<a-sky src="#skyTexture"></a-sky>
```

Comment: Please provide some code. How do you load the photo. Is it in `a-assets`. Are there any console errors?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Tomasz. I added the code for both of the scenarios I was testing to the original comment. The top html sources a random equirectangular photo hosted on Flikr that renders without issue. The bottom html has the equirectangular image I am trying to source from GCP. I neglected to look for console errors before since the Flikr image worked, but, yes, there is an error blocking access to the image due to a CORS policy. I'll research that error a bit, but feel free to provide input if you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with images from resource other than your own app, make sure to include `crossorigin="anonymous"` in your `img` tag, the error should disappear.

```
<img id="skyTexture" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/pano-images/cwm-vcfacility/PANO_20171019_130509_0.jpg">
```

It still won't work as you intend though. I don't know much about google storage, but I'd read the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin). If it works similarly to Amazon S3, then you'd have to enable your app to get access to the resource. In S3 it's done with XML rules.

**Last tips for working with images:**

- make sure they don't exceed 4096 x 2048 size
- make sure the size is power of two

If you don't follow this, it will be resized for you every time on page load - it takes time, so why not do it once.